# W 7 - how to stop third party software giving "access violation at address" on shutdown and hanging?

Tags: windows-7, shutdown

This is a bit of an "edge" case probably but I would be really grateful for ideas how to achieve this.

I've built a "fruit machine" cabinet that has a PC installed that runs some fruit machine emulation software. The PC isn't easily accessible so I've installed a 'physical' power on/off button, in easy reach, that is wired back to the power switch on the PC.

I've set up Windows 7 advanced power settings so that this button powers the PC on/off.

So far, so good... Unfortunately, when powering down the system hangs with a "access violation at address 007352BB in module mfme.exe. read of address 0000006c" message (mfme.exe being the software that is emulating the fruit machine).

Is there a way to "override" this and force the system to shut this process down? It does give me an option to "force shutdown" but I haven't got easy access to a mouse/keyboard so wondered if there was a way to make "force shutdown" the default rather than the PC asking me?

Thanks :)

Comment: Depending on what edition of Windows 7 you're running `gpedit.msc` should be available to change local Policies. I might be mistaken but I do think that there is a setting to force the shutdown after a timeout.

Comment: @Seth thanks Seth, I've found it. You're perfectly correct. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Seth's comment I've managed to find a solution to this on the net which is....

1.Press "Window +R" keys to start "Run" dialogue box and type "gpedit.msc" in the dialogue box.

2.Click "OK", "Local Group Policy Editor" window will pop up.

3.Navigate to "Computer Configuration" --> "Administrative Templates" --> "System" --> "Shutdown Options". Double-click "Turn off automatic termination of applications that block or cancel shutdown" on the right panel. In the new dialogue box popped up, set configuration option as "Enabled".

4.Next time when you shut down your machine, the machine will be shut down directly without prompt.